# How to get local calendar update callback

Tags: ios, iphone, ekeventstore

Is there any way to receive a callback from `EKEventStore` or from `EKCalendar` if an event is added to it from external sources (other device, google) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i have there is an listener to the `EKEventStore`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveEventStoreChangedNotification:) name:EKEventStoreChangedNotification object:nil];
```

and it get called every time when EventStore data  is changed.